How to Show a Blur Effect on My Screen Visible to All Connected Users?
I'm trying to implement a blur effect on my screen that should be visible to all other users connected to the video stream. Currently, the blur effect only shows on my own screen and not on others' screens.
Here's the code I'm using to apply the blur effect on the client side:
async handleProducer(id, type, stream) {
        let elem, vb, vp, ts, d, p, i, au, pip, fs, pm, pb, pn;
        switch (type) {
            case mediaType.video:
            case mediaType.screen:
                let isScreen = type === mediaType.screen;
                this.removeVideoOff(this.peer_id);
                d = document.createElement('div');
                d.className = 'Camera';
                d.id = id + '__video';
                elem = document.createElement('video');
                elem.setAttribute('id', id);
                !isScreen && elem.setAttribute('name', this.peer_id);
                elem.setAttribute('playsinline', true);
                elem.controls = isVideoControlsOn;
                elem.autoplay = true;
                elem.muted = true;
                elem.volume = 0;
                elem.poster = image.poster;
                elem.style.objectFit = isScreen || isBroadcastingEnabled ? 'contain' : 'var(--videoObjFit)';
                elem.className = this.isMobileDevice || isScreen ? '' : 'mirror';
                vb = document.createElement('div');
                vb.setAttribute('id', this.peer_id + '__vb');
                vb.className = 'videoMenuBar fadein';

                let vbToggle = document.createElement('button');
                vbToggle.id = id + '__BlurBackground';
                vbToggle.className = 'BlurToggle';
                vbToggle.innerText = 'Blur';
                vbToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
                  this.toggleBlur(elem.id);
                });
                vb.appendChild(vbToggle);

                pip = document.createElement('button');
                pip.id = id + '__pictureInPicture';
                pip.className = html.pip;
                fs = document.createElement('button');
                fs.id = id + '__fullScreen';
                fs.className = html.fullScreen;
                ts = document.createElement('button');
                ts.id = id + '__snapshot';
                ts.className = html.snapshot;
                pn = document.createElement('button');
                pn.id = id + '__pin';
                pn.className = html.pin;
                vp = document.createElement('button');
                vp.id = this.peer_id + +'__vp';
                vp.className = html.videoPrivacy;
                au = document.createElement('button');
                au.id = this.peer_id + '__audio';
                au.className = this.peer_info.peer_audio ? html.audioOn : html.audioOff;
                au.style.cursor = 'default';
                p = document.createElement('p');
                p.id = this.peer_id + '__name';
                p.className = html.userName;
                p.innerText = (isPresenter ? '⭐️ ' : '') + this.peer_name + ' (me)';
                i = document.createElement('i');
                i.id = this.peer_id + '__hand';
                i.className = html.userHand;
                pm = document.createElement('div');
                pb = document.createElement('div');
                pm.setAttribute('id', this.peer_id + '_pitchMeter');
                pb.setAttribute('id', this.peer_id + '_pitchBar');
                pm.className = 'speechbar';
                pb.className = 'bar';
                pb.style.height = '1%';
                pm.appendChild(pb);

                BUTTONS.producerVideo.muteAudioButton && vb.appendChild(au);
                BUTTONS.producerVideo.videoPrivacyButton && !isScreen && vb.appendChild(vp);
                BUTTONS.producerVideo.snapShotButton && vb.appendChild(ts);
                BUTTONS.producerVideo.videoPictureInPicture &&
                    this.isVideoPictureInPictureSupported &&
                    vb.appendChild(pip);
                BUTTONS.producerVideo.fullScreenButton && this.isVideoFullScreenSupported && vb.appendChild(fs);
                if (!this.isMobileDevice) vb.appendChild(pn);
                d.appendChild(elem);
                d.appendChild(pm);
                d.appendChild(i);
                d.appendChild(p);
                d.appendChild(vb);
                this.videoMediaContainer.appendChild(d);
                this.attachMediaStream(elem, stream, type, 'Producer');
                this.myVideoEl = elem;
                this.isVideoPictureInPictureSupported && this.handlePIP(elem.id, pip.id);
                this.isVideoFullScreenSupported && this.handleFS(elem.id, fs.id);
                this.handleDD(elem.id, this.peer_id, true);
                this.handleTS(elem.id, ts.id);
                this.handlePN(elem.id, pn.id, d.id, isScreen);
                this.handleZV(elem.id, d.id, this.peer_id);
                if (!isScreen) this.handleVP(elem.id, vp.id);
                this.popupPeerInfo(p.id, this.peer_info);
                this.checkPeerInfoStatus(this.peer_info);
                if (isScreen) pn.click();
                handleAspectRatio();
                if (!this.isMobileDevice) {
                    this.setTippy(pn.id, 'Toggle Pin', 'bottom');
                    this.setTippy(pip.id, 'Toggle picture in picture', 'bottom');
                    this.setTippy(ts.id, 'Snapshot', 'bottom');
                    this.setTippy(vp.id, 'Toggle video privacy', 'bottom');
                    this.setTippy(au.id, 'Audio status', 'bottom');
                }
                console.log('[addProducer] Video-element-count', this.videoMediaContainer.childElementCount);
               


    toggleBlur(videoElementId) {
        let videoElem = document.getElementById(videoElementId);
        if (videoElem) {
            if (!videoElem.classList.contains('blur-bg-applied')) {
                this.applyBlur(videoElem);
                videoElem.classList.add('blur-bg-applied');
            } else {
                this.removeBlur(videoElem);
                videoElem.classList.remove('blur-bg-applied');
            }
        }
    }

    applyBlur(videoElem) {
        // Apply background blur or image
        videoElem.style.filter = 'blur(50px)'; // For blur
        // Or for a background image, you might overlay a div with the image:
        let bgOverlay = document.createElement('div');
        bgOverlay.className = 'blur-bg-overlay';
        bgOverlay.style.backgroundImage = 'url(path/to/image.jpg)';
        videoElem.parentElement.appendChild(bgOverlay);
        bgOverlay.style.position = 'absolute';
        bgOverlay.style.top = '0';
        bgOverlay.style.left = '0';
        bgOverlay.style.width = '100%';
        bgOverlay.style.height = '100%';
        bgOverlay.style.zIndex = '-1';
    }
    removeBlur(videoElem) {
        // Remove background blur or image
        videoElem.style.filter = 'none';
        let bgOverlay = videoElem.parentElement.querySelector('.blur-bg-overlay');
        if (bgOverlay) {
            bgOverlay.remove();
        }
    }


The blur effect works perfectly on my screen, but it doesn't appear on the screens of other users. I'm struggling to figure out how to apply this effect server-side so that everyone in the connection can see my screen with the blur effect.
I've applied the blur effect on the client side, but it's not reflecting on others' screens.
I suspect that I need to handle this on the server side, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

You are simply applying the effect to an element (video player object) on your page. Users actually get the video's pixels so you must blur those pixels before making a video frame to send to them. You can use canvas to blur pixels (via some maths). Use the now blurred RGB pixels to make your new frames that you send. Not clear how you make/send the videoStream to a "connected user"...
